# Java function that blocks until a specific file is deleted

Tags: java, file

Created for a console application that will be run in the background on a linux system, giving me a nice way to gracefully shut it down by simply deleting a file (which can be done via script/etc.)

```
public class BlockOnRunFile {
    private File watchedFile;
    private Path path;
    private WatchService watcher;

    public void end() {
        watchedFile.delete();
    }

    public BlockOnRunFile(String runFilePath) throws IOException {
        watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(
                runFilePath.substring(0, runFilePath.lastIndexOf(FileSystems
                        .getDefault().getSeparator())));
        watchedFile = new File(runFilePath);
        watchedFile.createNewFile();
    }

    public void block() {
        try {
            WatchKey key;
            key = path.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);

            // stall until the game is supposed to end
            // reset key to allow new events to be detected
            while (key.reset()) {

                // key = watcher.take();
                try {
                    for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                        WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();
                        if (kind == StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW) {
                            Common.log.logMessage("File watcher overflow",
                                    LogLevel.INFO);
                            if (!watchedFile.exists()) {
                                // do nothing
                                ;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        if (kind == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE) {
                            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                            WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
                            Path filename = ev.context();
                            if (filename
                                    .toAbsolutePath()
                                    .toString()
                                    .equals(watchedFile.getAbsolutePath()
                                            .toString())) {
                                watcher.close();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000);   // prevent CPU burn, worst-case: 1 second delay on shutdown
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    watcher.close();
                    Common.log.logMessage(e, LogLevel.INFO);
                    continue;
                }
            }// end while loop
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Common.log.logMessage(e1, LogLevel.ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

It works, and I don't expect there to be any large amount of file operations in the directory where the file exists, but I would still like to know of any possible issues (I intend to automate it via some scripts/crontab and make sure it's robust enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting concept. I would link it in with, say, a pid file, and have the program terminate itself when the pid file is deleted.... and also delete it's own pid if it terminates early. I think that's why you have your `end()` method....

### General

> ```
> public class BlockOnRunFile {
>     private File watchedFile;
>     private Path path;
>     private WatchService watcher;
> ```

The above variables should all be final too. Also, there's an uncomfortable mix of the "old" `File`-based system, and the "new" `Path` based one. I recommend that you use `Path`, and stick to it.

### Simplifications

This code is.... ugly.

> ```
> path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(
>         runFilePath.substring(0, runFilePath.lastIndexOf(FileSystems
>                 .getDefault().getSeparator())));
> watchedFile = new File(runFilePath);
> watchedFile.createNewFile();
> ```

It can be simplified a lot:

```
Path watchedFile = Paths.get(runFilePath).toAbsolutePath();
Path runDir = watchedFile.getParent();
Files.deleteIfExists(watchedFile);
Files.createFile(watchedFile);
```

Note, there is no actual `File` instance in there, all just paths.... Also, there is no Watcher in there. There is no need to create the Watcher in the constructor, it is only used in the `block()` method, so use it there.

In your `block()` method, the try/catch is good, but I would add a finally:

```
} finally {
    Files.deleteIfExists(watchedFile);
}
```

The `Watcher` should be added as a resource to the top of that try.... and it auto-closes that way...

Also, about simplification, this code should be 1 line:

> ```
> WatchKey key;
> key = path.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);
> ```

like:

```
WatchKey key = runDir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);
```

Then, your code body, the guts, is a little more complicated than necessary, and has a bug....

The first thing is that the inner try/catch is unnecessary, and buggy. You cannot `close()` the `watcher` and then try to reset the key, and wait for more. That will just fail. The code will simply terminate the loop, yet you have a `continue` statement. It's unintuitive. I would simply remove the try/catch entirely.

The second bug is in the "OVERFLOW" code. Your code tests for if the file does ***not*** exist, but it should only continue if it ***does*** exist.

Finally, why do you have the `take()` commented out... and use a `Thread.sleep()`? The `take()` is a blocking operation, and will 'sleep' until there is an event ready. Use the logic in the `take()`, and trust it...

Oh, and your handling of `InterruptedException` is not good.....

Finally, you go to a lot of effort to make sure that every event in the directory is 'handled', but, there is no need to handle the events. All we need to do is to make sure our sentry file is still there. If it is gone, then we die. We don't care about any other files.... this essentially removes the need for the Overflow and other conditions....

### Suggestions

With the 'finally' block, the above fixes, and a little bit of "return" instead of "break", your code becomes:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;

public class BlockOnRunFile {
    private final Path watchedFile;

    public BlockOnRunFile(String runFilePath) throws IOException {
        watchedFile = Paths.get(runFilePath).toAbsolutePath();
        Files.deleteIfExists(watchedFile);
        // create entire directory tree, if possible, to create our watch file
        // in.
        Files.createDirectories(watchedFile.getParent());
        Files.createFile(watchedFile);

    }

    public void end() throws IOException {
        Files.deleteIfExists(watchedFile);
    }

    public void block() {
        try (WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
            final WatchKey key = watchedFile.getParent().register(watcher,
                    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);

            // stall until the game is supposed to end
            // reset key to allow new events to be detected
            while (key.reset()) {

                // wait for a file to be deleted (or an overflow....)
                if (key != watcher.take()) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(
                            "Only our key is registered, only it should be taken");
                }

                // now, we know something has changed in the directory, all we
                // care about though, is if our file exists.
                if (!Files.exists(watchedFile)) {
                    return;
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Common.log.logMessage(e1, LogLevel.ERROR);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // propogate an interrupt... we can't handle it here.....
            // just let the file be removed, and we die....
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            Common.log.logMessage(e, LogLevel.WARN);
        } finally {
            try {
                Files.deleteIfExists(watchedFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // unable to delete the sentry file.....
                Common.log.logMessage(e, LogLevel.WARN);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the "pid" part or the thread interrupt, but I will look into those - thanks for going over it, it seems I missed a lot of things.

Comment: On UNIX machines it is common for "server" software to write away their own process id in a server.pid file. (PID -> Process ID). That way it is easy for you to find which process your service is running as: `ls -la /var/run/*.pid`

Comment: Ah, in my case this is the only thing running java so I just use "pgrep java" to find the pid if I need it (so far it's only to do "pkill -9 java" if it doesn't shut down within a few seconds of this file being removed) - would this /var/run directory be the "standard" place for such a file? (and would it make sense for my app to place it's "run file" there?)

Comment: That's not a question I feel qualified to give a "yes it is the standard" answer on. Sure, for standard linux servers started through the upstart/init/rc.d/control systems it is typical. For applications that don't run as root, there's normally a folder in /var/run/ that is created for the application, with the right ownership, and permissions... It is the "right place" for such a thing, but only if you are really running as a system-wide service integrated in to the standard service system.

Answer (score 1):

I'll address functionality more than style, as I feel @rolfl has addressed style already.

**You don't actually block**

What you do is poll every 1 second. However the `WatchService` API is equipped to do actual blocking. I gather you tried doing that, but gave up (?) from the fact that this comment is left

```
            // key = watcher.take();
```

That is an actual blocking call. Assuming `watchedFile` is defined as a `Path`rather than as a `File` the block method should be like this :

```
public void block() {
    try (WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
        WatchKey key = path.register(watcher, ENTRY_DELETE, OVERFLOW);
        while (key.reset()) {
            try {
                key = watcher.take(); // this will actually block
                List<WatchEvent<?>> watchEvents = key.pollEvents();
                if (watchEvents.stream().filter(event -> ENTRY_DELETE.equals(event.kind())).anyMatch(event -> watchedFile.getFileName().equals(event.context()))) {
                    key.cancel();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                key.cancel();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This leaves out handling `OVERFLOW` for brevity.

**Inject the FileSystem**

As it is your code only works on the default file system. That is mostly fine, but refactoring it to have the `FileSystem` injected is not too hard, and enables testing it with the google's [jimfs](https://github.com/google/jimfs).